# Finding resourceDesign and resourcePage in Java for Adobe CQ

Tags: java, servlets, aem

I am working on a task that involves creating a servlet to take html requests in **Adobe CQ 5.5**. It requires pulling some objects defined by the [cq:defineObjects](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6/howto/taglib.html#par_title_7) tag. Two of these objects are **resourceDesign** and **resourcePage**.

I believe that I may possibly be able to retrieve resourceDesign from resourcePage with the following code:

```
import org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingAllMethodsServlet;
...
@Override
protected void doGet(SlingHttpServletRequest slingRequest, SlingHttpServletResponse      slingResponse) throws ServletException, IOException {
  ResourceResolver resourceResolver = slingRequest.getResourceResolver();
  ...
  Designer designer = resourceResolver.adaptTo(Designer.class);
  Page resourcePage = ...
  Design resourceDesign = designer.getDesign(resourcePage);
}
```

However I don't quite understand how to retreive the resourcePage and the documentation doesn't give a very clear idea of what it is or how to get its value.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Thomas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**resourcePage** refers to the page containing your resource and is an instance of `com.day.cq.wcm.api.Page`, and **resourceDesign** is the design object for the resource page.

The resourcePage can be obtained using PageManager's `#getContainingPage()` as shown here.

```
import org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingAllMethodsServlet;
...
@Override
protected void doGet(SlingHttpServletRequest slingRequest, 
    SlingHttpServletResponse slingResponse) throws ServletException, IOException {

    ResourceResolver resourceResolver = slingRequest.getResourceResolver();
    PageManager pageManager = resourceResolver.adaptTo(PageManager.class);

    Page resourcePage = pageManager.getContainingPage(slingRequest.getResource());

    Designer designer = resourceResolver.adaptTo(Designer.class);
    Design resourceDesign = designer.getDesign(resourcePage);
}
```

For more info, refer [this doc](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/developing/scripts.html#%3Ccq:defineObjects%3E).

Comment: Thank you rakhi, this response is great. The one thing I'm still slightly confused about is if there's a difference between resourcePage and currentPage (another object defined by the tag). I'm guessing now that the resourcePage refers to the page with the resources properties? Thanks, Thomas

Comment: Good question. Your `resourcePage` and `currentPage` both contains the same values, unless your resource is from a different place. i.e., in case you have included your resource using **absolute path**, you might find the value of resourcePage would vary from the currentPage.